# Dynamic Soap Url with Jax-rpc and netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans, netbeans-6.9, jax-rpc

when generating a web service client in netbeans 6.9 I would like the ability to dynamically load the soap endpoint url from a config (Properties) file (e.g. dev vrs production urls).  How can I accomplish that as netbeans ask for a literal url and then hard codes that url into multiple objects.

Answer (score 0):

```
URL url =  this.getClass().getResource("/package/dir/propFile.properties");
prop = new Properties();
prop.load(new FileInputStream(new File(url.getFile())));
```

Comment: this would be greate, if the jax-rpc netbeans plugin didn't automatically generate hard coded url's :(